# How to only add items to a list that haven't been added before? (C# - ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, list, lambda

I have a list that is being populated with the summed quantities of specific product ID's, for example:

My table:

[image]

My program checks for a user input and then compares that user input to the Quantity column in the table - once a match is found, the program checks for the ProductID of the matched quantity, and then adds ALL the quantities relating to that matched ProductID.

For example, if a user enters 2, the program will check for all the values in the Quantity column greater than or equal to 2 - so in this case, the first row to be found would be row 2 (which has a productID of 9 and a quantity of 2). The program should now search for ALL productID's equal to 9 and then sum their individual quantities (which will be 3 in this case, as the ProductID 9 appears only twice, with the quantities 2 and 1 respectively), and then save that final summed quantity (3) into the list. And then the program should continue to row 3 (which has a productID of 8 and a quantity of 3). The program should now search for ALL productID's equal to 8 and then sum their individual quantities (which will be 9 in this case, as the ProductID 8 appears three times, with the quantities 3 and 3 and 3 respectively), and then save that final summed quantity (9) into the list. And then the program should SKIP row 4, because the ProductID of 9 has already been dealt with - and so on and so forth.

So far i have tried this:

```
var dynamicReader = DBAccessor.InvoiceLines.Where(xx => xx.Quantity >= quantitySelected).Select(yy => yy.ProductID);

            foreach (var product in dynamicReader)
            {
                if (!quantityArrayList.Contains(product))
                {
                    quantityArrayList.Add(DBAccessor.InvoiceLines.Where(gg => gg.ProductID == product).Sum(g => g.Quantity));
                }
            }
```

If the user enters 2, the first 4 results using this method are correct, however, after that, the summed values fetched make little sense to me. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what you want is basically is the Quantity count grouping by ProductID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're not associating the `ProductID` with the `Quantity` stored in `quantityArrayList`. So, when you check `quantityArrayList.Contains(product)` you're not checking to see if that `ProductID` has already been processed, you're checking to see if there is a sum of quantities which match the `ProductID`.

I don't know what type `quantityArrayList` is, I'm assuming it's a `List<int>`. Instead, you should use a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2) where the key would be the `ProductID` and the value would be the sum of the `Quantity`.

Untested, but the updated code might look like...

```
Dictionary<int, int> productQuantities = new Dictionary<int, int>(); //I've changed the name, but this would replace quantityArrayList

var dynamicReader = DBAccessor.InvoiceLines.Where(xx => xx.Quantity >= quantitySelected).Select(yy => yy.ProductID);

foreach (var product in dynamicReader)
{
    if (!productQuantities.ContainsKey(product))
    {
        productQuantities.Add(product, DBAccessor.InvoiceLines.Where(gg => gg.ProductID == product).Sum(g => g.Quantity));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and additional information (I hadn't ever used Dictionary before) - I have tried to implement your solution, however, I am met by an error "Use of unassigned local variable 'productQuantities' (the error is coming from the productQuantities in the if statement.)

Comment: You have to assign it a value by newing up a `Dictionary<int, int>`. I've updated the answer, but basically: `Dictionary<int, int> productQuantities = new Dictionary<int, int>()`.

Comment: Alright perfect. And sorry, one last thing - would it be possible to assign the values of productQuantities to an array?

Comment: Just the values without the keys? You could use `productQuantities.Values.ToArray()` to get just the values (which would be the sum of the quantities) as an `array`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `GroupBy` with 2 values mapped to the grouping: `Max` and `Sum`. If the max quantity of one of the entries is greater than your desired amount, that grouping is 'in scope' and you want to get its sum. Like this:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var productCounts = new List<ProductCount>{
                new ProductCount{ProductId = 10, Quantity = 1},
                new ProductCount{ProductId = 9, Quantity = 2},
                new ProductCount{ProductId = 8, Quantity = 3},
                new ProductCount{ProductId = 9, Quantity = 1},
                new ProductCount{ProductId = 7, Quantity = 2},
                new ProductCount{ProductId = 5, Quantity = 3},
                new ProductCount{ProductId = 8, Quantity = 3},
                new ProductCount{ProductId = 6, Quantity = 2}
            };
            
            var desiredMinimum = 3;
            
            var output = productCounts.GroupBy(i => i.ProductId)
                .Select(i => new
                        {
                            ProductId = i.Key,
                            Max = i.Max(j => j.Quantity),
                            Total = i.Sum(j => j.Quantity)
                        })
                .Where(i => i.Max >= desiredMinimum)
                .ToList();
            
            foreach(var outputItem in output){
                Console.WriteLine("ProductId: " + outputItem.ProductId + "; Total: " + outputItem.Total);
            }
        }
        internal class ProductCount
        {
            public int ProductId{get;set;}
            public int Quantity{get;set;}
        }
    }
```

See:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/HmMc4h

Comment: Thank you for the solution - however, Joshua had something more along the lines of what i had been looking for.